# Labeling in ggplot on top of point

Tags: r, ggplot2, labeling

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
mpg %>%
  mutate(Color=ifelse(class=='2seater','2seater','Other')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(displ, hwy, colour = Color)) + 
  geom_point()
```

In the above code if i would like to separately label 2 wheeler on top of the blue dots for 2 wheeler instead of a separate column for legends, what would be the modification for my code pls?

Comment: What label would you like to add on top of your blue dots? You can add labels via e.g. `geom_text(aes(label = XXX))` or `geom_label`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but does this answer your question?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#install.packages("ggrepel")
library(ggrepel)
#Code
mpg %>%
  mutate(Color=ifelse(class == '2seater','2seater','Other')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(displ, hwy, colour = Color)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = ifelse(Color == '2seater', '2seater', "")),
                   ylim = 35, force_pull = 0, show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image: example_1.png]

Or perhaps this?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#install.packages("ggrepel")
library(ggrepel)
#Code
mpg %>%
  mutate(Color=ifelse(class == '2seater','2seater','Other')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(displ, hwy, colour = Color)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = ifelse(Color == '2seater', '2seater', "")),
                   force_pull = 0, show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: example_2.png]

Or some combination of the two?